# Why was this question about a syntax error in VB.NET closed as "Not A Real Question"

Tags: discussion, vote-to-close, specific-question

Here's the question I'm referring to at this point.

[Converted my code from C# to VB.NET and now it's throwing an error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9557283/converted-my-code-from-c-sharp-to-vb-net)

It's often frustrating seeing new users getting their questions closed too quickly because either:

1. It's in an undesirable language
2. It's not written with the most perfect grammar
3. People are just being pissy or some other invalid reason beyond my knowledge.

Can someone please explain to me why [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9557283/converted-my-code-from-c-sharp-to-vb-net) is closes as "Not A Real Question"?

(Note: I did edit it a little to help clarify the question).

Comment: I think that that question should be closed anyway, but for the other reason: it is too specific in current form and will not help future visitors.

Comment: not necessarily. If someone else comes up against a 'var is undefined` error, they could very well get the answer required.

Comment: The keypoint is `current form`. I do agree with you that this could be helpful in general form, e.g. if the question theme would be *var is undefined in vb*.

Comment: I'm pretty sure [OP reverting a good edit](http://stackoverflow.com/revisions/9557283/3) didn't help much... The [original version](http://stackoverflow.com/revisions/9557283/1) of the question was awful, although it should be noted that five users edited it and gradually brought it to shape (somewhat). However I don't really think we should berate close voters for not wasting any time on this. Closed questions can be re-opened if improved, closing it's just a peer review mechanism.

Comment: And you included info of the c# code and how it was converted (did you use a tool, website to convert it etc)

Comment: The OP did not include the original C# code.

Comment: And yes @YannisRizos I agree with you.

Comment: Just for the record, @Yannis, I'm quite sure the reversal of that edit was accidental. (The edit from Moo-Juice was saved at 17.43:43, and the OP's edit 17.43:57, making me believe the OP was oblivious about the other edit, and probably even started editing before Moo-Juice saved.)

Comment: @Arjan Good catch, I didn't notice that.

Comment: I can only guess it is the invisible force of the dreaded flag queue at work again.

Comment: @UphillLuge I have noticed this since reaching 10k rep. Now that there's a quick way to vote-to-close without actually reviewing the question. Many questions are killed in their infancy very unjustly.

Comment: Hmm, not so sure.  There were 5 high-rep users involved in closing it, 10 in re-opening it.  Afaict those users did the right thing.  How many were involved in the flag queue to push the moderator's buttons is invisible.  I'll guess there were not a lot of flags for keeping the question open.

Answer (score 7):

Looking at the question, it was incorrectly closed as "Not A Real Question".  It's a real question, and I see it's been reopened.

However, the question is "Too Localized" (and I've closed it as such, and remember, as always, that the community can vote to reopen if they wish), IMO, in that it's dealing with a *syntax error* in the code, something that is of little help to people in the future because of how narrow the scope is; it's an error in a *very* narrowly defined scope that has limited applications (i.e. that particular piece of code code).

There is some information there that could be of use, but I'd suggest a revamp of the question to point out the `var` aspect of the conversion in the code (there's a bit too much code there to really isolate the point) in order to get it reopened.

Comment: the question is STILL receiving reopen votes. Please understand that for VB, the question has enough detail to answer AND is an error that a larger group of people "could" run into.

Comment: @ChaseFlorell Well, if it's receiving open votes, then the system works, no?  Meta has a tendency to shine a light and put a lot of activity on a question that normally would not.

Comment: @ChaseFlorell Also, I've indicated that there is some value, that the questions just need some *work*; that's what closures are about, they say, "hey, you're off by a little bit, could you please try and fix it".  The reason we have different types of closures is to give people indicators about *what* to fix.

Comment: I've edited the question (a couple of times) to help bring light to the issue. I stripped the unnecessary code and clarified the question title.